# How to asynchronously push data to reactJs from Spring api web service to update a progress Bar?

Tags: spring, reactjs, web-services, rxjs, jax-rs

I have an application which allow an user to send a lot of SMS to his contacts (like thousands). 
Obviously that tasks can take a lot of time to complete.

So the idea is to display a progress bar on the client side, to indicate the user how many messages have been sent so far.

The back end of my app is a *restful spring webservice*.
The front end is done with **ReactJS and Redux**.

The question is:
Is it technically possible from the back end to periodically push data to the client, to update the progress bar, with the amount of messages already sent.

First question regarding the back end architecture:

I've seen that using JAX-RS 2 with spring, I can make asynchronous call in the back end, to execute other tasks(like querying the DB to see the messages already sent) while the other process is sending all messages. Am i looking in the right direction here ?

Second question regarding front end :
So far I use thunk functions for my requests(post/get) to the server, which returns a json response, and it works well. But in this case, the back end would periodically push data to the client side, until the main task is completed, so I don't understand how would that work out exactly ? 
I guess I'm not gonna be able to achieve that using the same request ? Should I look at other technologies to achieve that ?

Please let me know, if the description of my problem is not clear.
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

There are two options: you can keep track of the task on the backend and have an API endpoint to check the status and poll it every x seconds.

The other option would be to use sockets, the frontend client would listen for an event and update display onEvent. The backend would be responsible for emitting events.

Comment: I would opt for second option. After a bit of research I've found out I can achieve that using webflux, and websocket + redux socket.io

Comment: @jaybe78 I agree, this option will give full information, less of a choppy UI.